# How to store encrypted data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I'm developing an application that will have very sensitive data (api keys from other websites) and I need to store it encrypted in a db but without knowing them at any time.

Let me explain myself:

1. The form asks the user for his api keys
2. Encrypt them
3. Store it in the db

The main question is, how do I encrypt them in such a way that I can use them later (still without knowing them)?

Sorry if the question is silly, but I can't find a way to do it, and thanks.

Comment: https://medium.com/@getzired/a-simple-way-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-in-rails-5-9a514645d066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) for this. Works great.

```
  class User
    attr_encrypted :ssn, key: 'This is a key that is 256 bits!!'
  end
```

You then work with ssn as if it were a plain field

```
 user = User.find(1)
 puts user.ssn
```

but it's encrypted at rest (in the database) and can't be retrieved without the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
def encrypt text
  text = text.to_s unless text.is_a? String

  len   = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.key_len
  salt  = SecureRandom.hex len
  key   = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base).generate_key salt, len
  crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new key
  encrypted_data = crypt.encrypt_and_sign text
  "#{salt}$$#{encrypted_data}"
end

def decrypt text
  salt, data = text.split "$$"

  len   = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.key_len
  key   = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base).generate_key salt, len
  crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new key
  crypt.decrypt_and_verify data
end
```

Pass the key to `encrypt` method and store the returned encrypted value in DB.
Then to decrypt pass the encrypted key to the `decrypt` method.

This is assuming your Secret Key Base is in `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base`

The original source for the answer is [here](https://dev.to/shobhitic/simple-string-encryption-in-rails-36pi)

Comment: Useful when you need to encrypt data in flight, but when one only needs to _store_ it encrypted, then attr_encrypted offers much better effort/effect ratio, IMHO.

Comment: That said, I have a feeling that MessageEncryptor will come in handy in my current task :)

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to save passwords then attr_encrypted can be handy. But if you want to save API keys MessageEncryptor will do the job. Both have their own use cases.

Comment: Hm? There's literally no difference between the two (when applied to saving data to the database). Except one abstracts the persistence and encryption and the other doesn't. Why would one prefer MessageEncryptor if their goal is to _save_ encrypted data? It's just more work for no benefit at all.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of something else! You're correct both does the similar job!!